# Rails lazy loads my model's rb file, forcing me to write slightly uglier code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I've got a model in my rails app (app/models/foo.rb), like so:

```
class Foo
    def initialize(bar)
        @bar = bar
    end

    def puts_bar
        puts @bar
    end
end

def Foo(bar)
    Foo.new(bar)
end
```

When I try to use this model like this:

```
Foo(bar).puts_bar
```

it can't find it because it hasn't loaded the model's file yet.  If I use the model like this:

```
Foo.new(bar).puts_bar
```

Rails goes out and finds my model and loads it (and after that my foo function works too).

How can I tell Rails to load my model file so my foo function works from the start?

Comment: I'm really confused by this question... your class name starts with a lower-case letter, so is it possible that there's some collisions going on? Should it be class Foo and not foo? It might also help if you could describe the problem, because it seems to me you're doing some sort of factory, which you might be able to use a class method for instead.

Comment: Yeah, there are few weird things here, like passing an object through an intializer, and then putting it with a method, unless its some sort of proof of concept.

Comment: fixed the capitalization of Foo.

Comment: String appears to me to do the same sort of thing.  You can call `String('foo')` or `String.new('foo')` and they both create a String object with contents of 'foo'.  That's the sort of functionality I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you've made `puts_bar` an instance method, but you are trying to use it like a class method. These are incompatible.

Initialize won't happen until you "new up" a foo. to get around this you could do:

```
class Foo
  def self.puts_bar(bar)
    puts bar
  end
end
```

this will allow you to do:

```
Foo.puts_bar(bar)
```

Comment: My example is a little contrived, I guess.  I want it to be an instance method because sometimes I will call several instance methods on this object and I want them all to have access to the instance variable @bar that I set earlier when creating the instance.

Comment: If it has to be an instance method, then you have to run it through new first, otherwise you've never actually created an instance.

Comment: `Foo(bar).puts_bar` would call the Foo function which calls new and creates an instance.  It all works.... when Rails loads the rb file.  My problem is not that it doesn't work.  It's that Rails doesn't load it until you try to access the Foo class (accessing the Foo function doesn't cause it to load).

Answer (score 1):

You could put something like this into `config/initializers/ugly_hack.rb` (or whatever filename you like ;)

```
Dir.chdir File.join( Rails.root, 'app', 'models' ) do
  Dir['**/*.rb'].each do |f|
    f.slice! ".rb"
    model_class = f.classify
    eval <<-EOI
    def #{model_class} *args
      #{model_class}.new( *args )
    end
    EOI
  end
end
```

This will take all the files in your `app/models` directory, and create methods for them.  It's not creating those methods within the model file, so not relying on the lazy loading to make those methods available.

Comment: That's hysterical -I was writing almost the identical thing when I saw the notification. I want to add that I don't think this is a good or necessary idea, but then again I don't understand the OP's question.

Comment: I'm hoping the filename I chose means that I don't need to comment on whether I think this is a good idea or not :)